# How to implement web service loading with pagination in UITable with UIButtons?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, pagination

I need to implement the pagination in UITableView in such a way like this

If the number of records exceeds the number of rows allowed for the screen like 5, then the application shall automatically show pagination control.

The pagination pane shall allow the user to navigate between the pages using the buttons on the pane.
The buttons on the pagination pane are of two types:

Single page navigation: these buttons allow navigation only through one page at a time.

Multiple page navigation: these buttons allow the user to skip a number of pages at a time.

here is the code executed by me. But how to fetch the web service based on this.?

```
    @interface ViewController (){
    //pageNumber will hold the current page index
    NSInteger _pageNumber;
    //keeping the max page number for ease of calculation
    NSUInteger _maxPageNumber;
    //the batch size
    NSUInteger _numberOfVisibleRows;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Main data array is formed
    NSUInteger rows = 0;
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    while (rows<52) {

        [tempArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item %d",rows+1]];
        rows++;
    }

    self.mainArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tempArray];

    _pageNumber = 0;
    _numberOfVisibleRows = 5;
    _maxPageNumber = [self.mainArray count]/_numberOfVisibleRows;

    self.subArray = [self subArrayForPageNumber:_pageNumber];

}

- (NSArray *)subArrayForPageNumber:(NSUInteger)pageNumber{

    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(_pageNumber*_numberOfVisibleRows, _numberOfVisibleRows);
    if (range.location+range.length>[self.mainArray count]) {
        range.length = [self.mainArray count]-range.location;
    }
   return [self.mainArray subarrayWithRange:range];
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIBarButtonItem *)button{
    //Same method is used for calculating the page numbers
    if (button.tag ==1) {
        _pageNumber= MIN(_maxPageNumber, _pageNumber+1);
    }else{
        _pageNumber = MAX(0, _pageNumber-1);
    }

    self.subArray = [self subArrayForPageNumber:_pageNumber];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Comment: which kind of pagination you need ? like load more or left/right scroll pagination ?

Comment: left / right scroll pagination

Comment: the you can use pageViewController.

Comment: a GitHub source code will be great help...

Comment: tutorial for pagination : http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/

Comment: github link : https://github.com/hyperoslo/Pages

Comment: thanks if we need to implement it on load more button then?

Comment: what you want to display actually in tableview ?

Comment: some datas from webservice

Comment: ok you need to call webservice at last indexpath .

Comment: okay how to implement a skip button